# Comparing group differences across two domains

Tags: testing, statistics, difference

I have two response item variables, both measured on a 5-point Likert scale. For both variables, I find statistically significant gender differences (Mann-Whitney U test). What test or method can I use to test whether one gender difference (in variable 1) is relatively larger than the other gender difference (in variable 2)?

Many thanks for your help!

I tried Ologit, but as I used MWU test before, I am not sure whether Ologit is the right method

Comment: Welcome to SO. As written, this question is asking for recommendations on a statistical test and is more appropriate for Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Questions here must be about a specific programming problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20only%20accepts%20certain,it%20will%20likely%20be%20closed.). Please adjust your question according to these recommendations or it may be closed.